# Refactor validation of the drop down and text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, validation

I need to validate a text field based on the dropdown. I have two scenarios here
1. When the user changes the value in the dropdown and then enter the text in the textfield
2. The user enters the text in the text field and then changes the dropdown.

I have written code for two cases which seems to working fine. But I am not sure if I have everything right. Can I refactor my code or my code is fine.

In addition, I need to validate the text field to alphanumeric characters and underscore, which doesn't seem to work.

Please excuse my ignorance as I am new to jquery. I have posted my code here: http://jsfiddle.net/qbrJv/

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Jquery validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation). This plugin already implements alot of useful features for client-side validation.

So using this plugin all you need to do is:

1. implement your own validator which will use the value of drop-down to validate value in text box
2. attach this validator to a text box

Validation for alphanumeric and underscor also can be implemented like separate validators and attached to an input.

As a benefit you can reuse such validators across your application.

Comment: to include the plugins I need to go through legal team, which is a pain and would take more time to get it approved. I would appreciate if you can let me know if the code I have written can be refactored